# How many users is enough to crash the online mysql DB(http://www.db4free.net/)?

Tags: mysql, database, crash

I have approx 10 000 users, one user is requesting whole db information (appr 10 000 rows) once a second. Is it enough for MYsql DB to crash??
Thanks

Comment: yes it is enought )))

Comment: Crash, probably not, be too slow, quite probably.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on many things, such as

- The specs of the server (e.g. how fast the disk / memory is)
- The setup of mysql (e.g. how much memory it is allocated)
- The engine used in MySQL (e.g. MyISAM locks the whole table when somebody wants to use a row)
- The structure of any query (e.g. sorting on a non-indexed row will be slow)
- How much information is in each row (the more information, the longer it takes to read it)

Either way, the situation does not sound ideal. You would be much better of caching the result of the query on disk somehow, as reading from a disk is faster than reading from a database.

Hope that helps!